# java/jsf/hibernate

Tags: java

how to integrate jsf with hibernate,send me an example.

Comment: try: public void integrate(jsf, hibernate) { doIt(please) } - The please is important!

Comment: For "integrating" jsf and hibernate i would reccomend the maven-shade-plugin, it should extract all dependencies and create one integrated jar of both libraries :)

Answer (score 3):

Did you try http://www.google.com/search?aq=2&oq=jsf+hiber&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jsf+hibernate+example

some result:

[Build a real-world Web application with JavaServer Faces, the Spring Framework, and Hibernate](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-07-2004/jw-0719-jsf.html)